# Unable to use Bootstrap Dynamic Tabs on Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, tabs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add **Dynamic Tabs** to my Wordpress Theme (Hestia) by using Bootstrap code as the example showed in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h).

> For information, the "Hestia" Theme does already contain Bootstrap css and js and the following lines of code on the "function.php" file of the theme to run Bootstrap:

```html
function my_scripts_enqueue() {
   wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue' );
```

To create the **Dynamic Tabs**, I am adding the same code as the one in the exemple on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h) into my post:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The **problem** is that when I test this code on my XAMPP local server using my Wordpress Theme I can see the **Tabs** but they are **not responsive/dynamic**.

How can I solve this? Any idea of why is not working?

Thanks for your help!